# Touched is not a valid member of Model

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried to create a script on roblox that makes a tree fall down i.e (un-anchor) when touched, however when I run the script, it creates an error.

**Problem**

```
16:36:55.978  theIivingtribunaI committed a new version of script
    Workspace.Tree.Script  -  Studio
16:36:58.555  Touched is not a valid member of Model "Workspace.Tree"  -  Server - Script:9
16:36:58.555  Stack Begin  -  Studio
16:36:58.555  Script 'Workspace.Tree.Script', Line 9  -  Studio - Script:9
16:36:58.555  Stack End  -  Studio
```

**Code**

```
local fallingdown = script.Parent
function makingTheTreeFallDown(hit)
    local tree
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        fallingdown.Anchored=false
    end
end
    
script.Parent.Touched:connect(makingTheTreeFallDown)
```

I want the script to allow the tree (object) to be un-anchored when touched.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that a [Model](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Model) doesn't have a Touched event. Only [BaseParts](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BasePart) have a Touched event. It also doesn't have an Anchored property.

So to fix your code, you need to tell a specific Part to unanchor when touched.

It may be a little overkill, but you can do this by looping over all the parts and unanchoring them all.

```lua
local treeModel = script.Parent
local parts = {}
local connections = {}

-- when any part is touched, unanchor every part in the tree
local function makeTreeFallDown(hit)
    -- make sure that the thing that touched this is a character model
    local hasHumanoid = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if not hasHumanoid then
        return
    end

    for _, part in ipairs(parts) do
        part.Anchored = false
    end

    -- remove all touched connections so this doesn't fire multiple times
    for _, connection in ipairs(connections) do
        connection:Disconnect()
    end
end

-- find all the parts in the model, and listen for touch events
for _, part in ipairs(treeModel:GetDescendants ()) do
    if part:IsA("BasePart") then
        local connection = part.Touched:Connect(makeTreeFallDown)
        table.insert(connections, connection)
    end
end
```

This method will preserve the welds and constraints between the parts. So if the Tree is welded to the baseplate, unanchoring the parts won't cause it to fall down. If you want the whole thing to fall apart, you can use the `Model:BreakJoints()`. But the best thing to do is simply break the specific weld between the tree parts and the baseplate.